# Replacing IF with a logical expression in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, expression, ternary

I was refactoring some old code when I stumbled upon a construct similar to this:

```
// function bar() returns a value
// if the value is an instance of customException class, terminate with error code
// else process the regular data

$foo = bar();
checkForException($foo) && exit($foo->errorCode());
process($foo);
```

Now strange as it might seem, this is a lot shorter then

```
$foo=bar();
if(checkForException($foo)) {
    exit($foo->errorCode();
}
else {
    process($foo);
}
```

And somewhat more readable (at least after the initial surprise) then

```
$foo=bar();
(checkForException($foo)) ? exit($foo->errorCode()) : process($foo);
```

While shorter code doesn't necessarily mean more readable code, I find this to be somewhere in the middle of the two "standard" ways above.

In other words, instead of

```
if($foo) {
    bar();
}
else {
    // there is no real reason for this to exist, since 
    // I have nothing to write here, but I want to conform 
    // to the general coding practices and my coding OCD
}
```

One could simply write

```
$foo && bar();
```

So what is the reasoning behind this not seeing much use? Can it be as simple as "Don't reinvent the wheel, write the more readable if/else, and if you really want to shorten it, that's what ternary operator is for"?

EDIT: Please keep in mind that the above code was quickly derived from the original code and was mean to be just an example of the use of "short circuit" code. If you can, please restrain from suggesting code improvements, since that was not the desired outcome of the question.

Example No.2

```
userCheckedTheBox($user) && displayAppropriateInfo();
```

Comment: In a structured framework, you won't be using `exit` that much. Besides that, a full `if/else` allows you to use multiple instructions in the `else` branch - anyways sometimes short circuitation is very very useful, just don't abuse that.

Comment: Why should it be "strange" (as in "strange as it might seem") that less characters are shorter than more characters? You must live a sheltered life.

Comment: "So what is the reasoning behind this not seeing much use?" --- because there are different types of programmers: some write "cool" code, another - easy to support one.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the _return value_ is an instance of an Exception object?? Why isn't the exception thrown? that way, you can have that Ever so clear, not at all outlandish `throw-catch` block

Comment: I've modified the code to try to create an illustrative example (agreeably not the best one).
@CaptainPayalytic "strange as it might seem" refers to the code above

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem: if the code original author threw an exception (as it's supposed) then he wouldn't have a chance to use a new cool technique he had learnt a day before.

Comment: That's what code refactoring is for...

Not to discourage expressing your opinions about the capability of programmers, but this is going a little off subject...

Comment: @user1853181: _not_ throwing Exceptions is about as silly as it gets... IMHO, pointing that out isn't off topic at all here. Debating the use of ternaries, and various other shorthand coding tricks shouldn't take precedence over misuse of Exception handling...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an old technique which I believe was popular in hacked-together perl scripts to show errors. pseudo-code:

```
myFunction( ) || exitWithError( "Uh-oh" )
```

When coding-to-a-deadline, and when the user interface doesn't need to be stellar, it's a quick way to avoid errors.

The style is also popular in javascript for default parameters:

```
function myfunction(foo) {
    foo = foo || 0;
    // note that a non-zero default won't work so well,
    // because the user could call the function with 0
}
```

and for null-checks:

```
var bar = foo && foo.property;
```

I find that once you're used to it, it's very readable and often more intuitive than `if`/`else` or `?:`. But you should only use it when it makes sense. Using it everywhere is going to get very confusing. For example, in your example, you should *not* use it. Personally I use it for simple error checking and *some* default values. In big projects, you almost always want to do a lot more when an error occurs, so in those cases you shouldn't use this.

Also you should be careful; this only works in languages which have short-circuit evaluation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). And sometimes `and` and `or` are short-circuit, while `&&` and `||` are not.

`myfunction() or die("I'm melting!");` is also quite satisfying to write.

Finally, empty `else` blocks as a rule is something I've never seen before, or heard anyone recommend. It seems very pointless to me. The most readable option for your example is, quite simply:

```
if( $foo ) {
    bar( );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

While `$foo && bar();` is fewer lines of code it's much less readable. Making your code easy to understand is usually more important than reducing the total LoC. Even if it's you're not working in an environment with multiple programmers, you will have to come back and read your code at some point in the future, and you probably won't be able to remember what the rationale was behind every line of code ([Eagleson's Law](http://hackersays.com/0da6e0)).

Generally, you should limit the use of these kinds of statements to only those cases where the programmer's intent is absolutely clear. In my opinion, it's very bad practice to have code which tests a condition and code which actively modifies the current state of the program on the same statement.

Here's one acceptable use for this kind of code:

```
$isValidUser = $userName && usernameIsValid();
```

Here, both sides of the `&&` operator are testing a condition, the fact that the right side is calling a function to do that does not harm the readability of the code.

Answer (score 1):

For errors you should use real exceptions:

```
try {
  $foo = bar();
} catch(FooException $e) {
  exit($e->errorCode);
}
process($foo);
```

See [the documentation for errorhandling](http://php.net/manual/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: OP _is_ using real exceptions (`customException `), they're just not being thrown, but used as a return value...

Answer (score 1):

What ever that code is doing, returning an instance of `CustomException` just doesn't add up. Why not change the function definition a little:

```
function bar()
{
     $stuff = true;
     if ($stuff === true)
     {
         return 'Value on success';
     }
     //something went wrong:
     throw new CustomException('You messed up');
}
try
{//here's the outlandish try-catch block
     $foo = bar();
}
catch (CustomException $e)
{
    exit($e->message());//fugly exit call, work on this, too
}
//carry on here, no exception was thrown
```

Also, calling that second function (`checkForException($foo)`) is just absurd. Function calls are cheap, but not free. You want to know if the function returned an instance of `CustomException`? Don't turn that into a function, but use `instanceof`. Using short-circuit to keep the number of chars (ad thus parse-time) down, while at the same time wasting resources on on all other levels is about as silly as turning up in a V8 mustang on a hyper-miling course.

Comment: I have edited my question to better reflect it's desired outcome. Exceptions are being thrown and handled, the names are just a tad unfortunate.

Comment: @user1853181: Sorry to keep banging on like this, but clearly you're not throwing the exception. If you were, the short-circuit evaluation would fail, and all you'd see is a message saying `Error: uncaught Exception`

Comment: As far as I understood, the exception handler in bar() is logging the exception info and returning the custom object (with an error code among the other info) to the caller. I'm sure there was a good intention behind that, trying to figure it out right now... But this is really topic for another question, if the need arises.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible Solution for your problem:

```
$foo = bar();
!checkForException($foo) or exit($foo->errorCode);
process($foo);
```

But better change `!checkForException` for `isNoException` or something along those lines.